# Задача про обиженного короля

Tags: python, циклы, условия

Король после пира в своём дворце дал команду страже арестовать 100 звездочётов, так как они позже всех пришли на празднество и этим его обидели. Он был любителем поиграть и приказал звездочётам выстроиться в ряд, задумав надеть на их головы синие и красные шляпы. После построения им будет запрещено общаться, издавать какие-либо звуки, оглядываться и снимать шляпы. Однако разрешено смотреть на шляпы стоящих спереди и слушать ответы стоящих сзади.

Король будет подходить к каждому звездочёту и задавать один и тот же вопрос: «какого цвета твоя шляпа?»

Учёные должны ответить на вопрос короля только одним словом: «красная» или «синяя». Неверный ответ карается тихой смертью, а за верный даруется жизнь (но всё равно придётся стоять безмолвно).

Король доходчиво объяснил, что в случае нарушения правил будет казнена вся сотня участников его игры. После чего разрешил учёным посовещаться.

Какой алгоритм поможет спасти максимальное количество звездочётов?

Обратите внимание Шляпы на головы звездочётов надевает король, обход начинается с конца. Люди выстроены таким образом, что смотрят друг другу в затылок.

как реализовать данную задачу на Python
Вроде как нашел ответ в инете, но в письменной форме. Решил написать программу и вылазит ошибка 'not all arguments converted during string formatting'

```
k = 0
death_score = 0
saved_lifes = 0
number_of_wizards = 100


while k <= 100:
    blue_hats = input('Сколько синих шляп перед тобой? ')
    z = input(str('Скажи цвет шляпы на голове: '))
    for h in range(100):
        if blue_hats % 2 == 0 and z == 'red':
            saved_lifes += 1
            k += 1
        
        elif blue_hats % 2 == 1 and z == 'red':
            death_score += 1
            number_of_wizards -= 1
            k += 1
        else:
            None
print(saved_lifes)
```

Comment: Ответ -- цвет шляпы, стоящего впереди. Если первый не угадал (его цвет отличается от цвета перед ним), то умрет только он.

Comment: @avp Да а следующий что выкинет. Цвет который назвал предыдущий? Тогда  что делать 3 му?

Comment: @AzizUmarov, главное, чтобы они верили в этот "алгоритм". Тогда половина из них (та что не угадала) умрет легко

Answer (score 1):

Насчёт того, почему возникает ошибка `not all arguments converted during string formatting`.

```
blue_hats = input('Сколько синих шляп перед тобой? ')
```

В переменной `blue_hats` у вас строка. Посмотрим, что у вас здесь:

```
blue_hats % 2
```

Питон воспринимает этот код не как "возьми остаток от деления на 2", а как старый вариант подстановки переменных в строку, сейчас редко применяющийся. Поскольку есть что подставлять (число 2), а куда это подставлять непонятно (нет специальных символов в строке, означающих, что в это место нужно подставить переменную), у вас и выходит такая ошибка. Исправить её, можно преобразовав переменную `blue_hats` в целое число:

```
blue_hats = int(input('Сколько синих шляп перед тобой? '))
```

После этого код `blue_hats % 2` будет восприниматься как было задумано.

Comment: Решил изменить код и убрал цикл for. Вместо него поставил while и чтобы проверить работоспособность кода, изменил значение 100 на 10. Когда проверял количество итераций превышало условие цикла. https://pastebin.pl/view/10331d34